# Using Classes in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, class, vue.js

I'm relatively new to Vue, so if this is a stupid question I apologize.

Is it possible to use either ES6 classes or a class function in a Vue object? I'm trying to implement an AI  for my Tic-Tac-Toe project using the Minimax algorithm, and I need to make a constructor for my States. But in the Vue object, references to 'this' refer to the Vue object itself, even when wrapped in a class function it would seem. So I'm wondering how I could get around this, or if there is an easier way to accomplish this. Thanks!

[Here is the link I'm using for the Minimax algo.](https://mostafa-samir.github.io/Tic-Tac-Toe-AI/)

[And the link to my Codepen.](http://codepen.io/Dirtier/pen/ALxWLy)

```
console.clear();
const log = console.log.bind(console);

const game = new Vue({
el: '#app',
data: {
    turn: 'X',
    counter: 0,
    winner: '',
    started: false,
    over: false,
    header: {
        X: 'color',
        O: ''
    },

    sound() {
        const tick = new Audio('https://dl.getdropbox.com/s/kgqqnei0yhv3r8n/219069__annabloom__click1.wav')
        if(this.over)
            tick.play();
    },

    board: [[{val:'',bg:''}, {val:'',bg:''}, {val:'',bg:''}],
                  [{val:'',bg:''}, {val:'',bg:''}, {val:'',bg:''}],
                  [{val:'',bg:''}, {val:'',bg:''}, {val:'',bg:''}]],

    windex: [[[0,0], [0,1], [0,2]],
                     [[1,0], [1,1], [1,2]],
                     [[2,0], [2,1], [2,2]],
                     [[0,0], [1,0], [2,0]],
                     [[0,1], [1,1], [2,1]],
                     [[0,2], [1,2], [2,2]],
                     [[0,0], [1,1], [2,2]],
                     [[0,2], [1,1], [2,0]]],

    arr() {
        return this.board.map( x => x.map( y => y.val ));
    },

    winArr() {
        return this.windex.map( x => x.map( y => this.board[y[0]][y[1]].val ));
    },

    check() {
        const winArr = this.winArr();
        const checkWindex = winArr.map( (x,ind) => {
            if( x.every( y => y == 'X' )) return 'X';
            if( x.every( y => y == 'O' )) return 'O';
        });
        if(checkWindex.includes('X'))
            this.setWin('X',checkWindex)
        else if(checkWindex.includes('O'))
            this.setWin('O',checkWindex)
        else if(this.counter == 9) {
            this.winner = 'DRAW';
            setTimeout(() => this.over = true, 0);
        };
    }
},

methods: {
    mark(box) {
        this.header[this.turn] = 'color';
        if(this.over) return
        if(box.val === ''){
            box.val = this.turn;
            this.turn = this.turn == 'X' ? 'O' : 'X';
        }
        this.counter++;
        this.check();
        this.header.X = this.turn == 'X' ? 'color' : '';
        this.header.O = this.turn == 'O' ? 'color' : '';
    },

    setWin(val,arr) {
        const inds = this.windex[arr.indexOf(val)];
        inds.forEach( x => {
            this.board[x[0]][x[1]].bg = 'active';
        });
        this.winner = val;
        setTimeout(() => this.over = true, 0);
    },

    start(mode) {
        this.started = true;
        this.counter = 0;
        this.board.map( x => x.map( y => { y.val = ''; y.bg = '' }));
        this.over = false;
    }
}
});
```

Comment: congrats for your game. this is cool. : ) about the question you ask here, you should try to reduce the scope as much as possible to make your problem more obvious. Don't throw all your app's code

Comment: Haha thanks. But good point. The question doesn't really have that much to do with the code anyway, I was just wondering if there was a way to do this. Should I just take the code out?

Comment: well, it depend if you expect an answer…

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component? Also: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/2371